# How to create mutliple spans from within a Backbone view

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, each

I have a a collection of model data that I need to render inside a **div** like this:

```
_.each(model.stages, function(stagesData){
                    this.$('.stageDate').text(stagesData.get('status'));
                    this.$('.stageStatus').text(stagesData.get('timestamp'));
                });
```

This is the `HTML` where I'm trying to render that data:

```
 <span class="stageDate"></span>
 <span class="stageStatus"></span>
```

Now what's happening right now is that it only shows the last item inside my Model in the view and not all. I know that it is because the loop overwrites the previously created span, so just wanted to understand what is the way to go about it? Please suggest!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of `text()`:

```
this.$('.stageDate').text(stagesData.get('status'));
```

Use `append()`:

```
this.$('.stageDate').append('</p>' + stagesData.get('status') + '</p>');
```